# Android localization error

Tags: java, android

Please help me!
I have one simple app,where there are 'Editetext' ,Folders: values-ru,values,values-hy  for localization.I want give Edittext hint from appropriate  values folder.
But confused ,and example for "en" ,take values from values-hy.

```
            Locale locale = new Locale("en");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
    ed.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.text));`
```

Comment: As I understand you are changing locales during the execution many times. Is this correct?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the manifest.  You're not using android:configChanges are you?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

for

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
   getApplicationontext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: I'm curious to understand how this will localise the OPs strings.

Comment: Don't know, I'm waiting for response. I've just made some investigation in code I have. This was the only difference I've found. BTW, this way of changing locales is NOT recommended.

Comment: It happens only case hint text

Comment: M-m-m, didn't catch it, sorry. Works or not?